# Text buiding blocks

Tags: discusión

In our sister site [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com), there's a list of pre-designed replies, known as [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/3954), that are used quite often. This list is quite helpful to give some standard replies with a simple and quick copy&paste, so I thought that it might be useful to have our own list here.

I'll initially post here some of the blocks that (I consider) apply here. If you think this idea is useful, this “question” will be community wiki, so please feel free to add/delete blocks and improve existing ones.

#### Non-answers

- *Welcome to Spanish.SE! Your question won't be seen by many people here so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. Follow-up questions like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.*
- *Instead of posting a “Thank you” as an additional answer, you should thank [user] by upvoting [his/her] answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark). We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers, so this non-answer will be removed from public view soon.*
- *Instead of “answering” your own question, you should comment on [user]'s answer or edit the original question to include the additional information.*

  And optionally: *(You may have to register at Spanish.SE in order to do so.)*

#### Migrated questions/users

- *Welcome to Spanish.SE! Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.*

  To make the comment more personal, you can replace another stackexchange site with the respective link, i.e. [so], [su] or [sf] for the big three or [something.se] for everything else, e.g. [english.se].

#### Intro / closing

- *Welcome to Spanish.SE! You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.*

  Alternatively:
- *Welcome to Spanish.SE! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.*

  And optionally: *A suggestion: Change your username to something more telling than "user3661".*

  Alternatively:
- *Welcome to Spanish.SE! Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.*

#### Possible duplicates

For new(ish) users whose question looks like it might get closed as a duplicate. If someone's already suggested a question

- *Please take a look at the questions that others have suggested as the answers there might help you. If they do, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If they don't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.*

  If not,
- *This question is very similar to these others INSERTLINKS. Please take a look at them as the answers there might help you. If they do, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If they don't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.*

#### For "closed as duplicate" questions:

- *If the linked question doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question to explain why and we'll reopen it. Closing as a duplicate is just a way of ensuring that people who find this question easily find the other one.*

#### Please ‘accept’ an answer below

One should wait a day before leaving this comment:

- *Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).*
- *Note that in case of a self-answer one has to wait 48 hours (after the question was posted) before accepting.*

#### Upload images only over the official interface

- *Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire.*
- *As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.*

Comment: Are there *unofficial* ways to upload an image??

Comment: @hippietrail Yes, there are. When I started on *TeX.SX* I used to load the images directly to *imgur* and then used `![](<link>)` to upload the images in my posts. After some time, more than 250 images were lost and we had to re-upload them!

Comment: I naively assumed imgur was some shadowy part of Stack Exchange somehow...

Comment: Regarding the **Intro or Closing** section, just edit the post!  There's no need to add a comment to the post, in my opinion.

Comment: @Richard: yes, that's the thing to do. However, in TeX.SX we use to leave the comment so the new(ish) OP can easily find out why his question was edited to remove the greeting/sign.